# Azure DevOps Rest API to create a new PAT

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Unable to create new PAT for a specific organization using the Rest API as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1). The following request is throwing a 403Forbidden error where I'm the owner of the organization and using a PAT with full access.

```
POST https://vssps.dev.azure.com/myproject/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=6.1-preview.1

{
  "displayName": "new_token",
  "scope": "vso.agentpools_manage",
  "validTo": "2021-08-26T03:21:20.576Z",
  "allOrgs": false
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where  to find the valid values for "scope" ? There's nothing in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#request-body

Comment: Scopes to use can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#scopes

Answer (score -1):

You need to change to use **Azure AD token**.

you can refer to [Manage personal access tokens (PATs) using REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops#prerequisites)

> With this PAT Lifecycle Management API, we’ve opened up the ability to
> create new PATs and revoke existing PATs. In the wrong hands, this API
> could be used by malicious actors to create multiple entry points into
> your organization’s ADO resources. By enforcing Azure AD
> authentication, we hope to have this powerful API be more secure
> against this unauthorized usage.

which means to prevent malicious actor and leak information, the enforcing of Azure AD provide level of secure protection against unauthorized usage.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's question. Any user added to Azure DevOps can hit this API for creating their own PAT tokens; you can also use an Azure AD App Registration that can manage them at an Org level.